# Stop VLC Player playlist at last item

Tags: vlc-media-player

When I click PgDn (Page Down) key in the keyboard, VLC moves to the next item in the playlist. After the last item, it moves to the first item, on page down. How can I change the settings so that the behaviour is the same, except when I click page down when the last item in the playlist is playing, nothing should happen? I did not find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the option to quit the player at the end of playlist (in the Media menu).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, that setting had no effect for me. The player pauses at the last frame (just as I want). But, on clicking PgDn button, the first item is getting played. There should be nothing after the last item. For me, first item comes after the last item. My loop setting is off. But still, it loops.